# Integration by substitution/other methods?

Tags: integration

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use integration by substitution here, but here's the question:

$$\int ^{10}_{0}f\left( x\right) dx=25$$
Find the value of
$$\int ^{e^{2}}_{1}\dfrac {f\left( 5\times \ln \left( x\right) \right) }{x}dx$$
Do I let $$u = 5\ln(x)$$ and substitute?
Cheers

EDIT: I substituted and found the following

$$\frac{1}{5}\int_0^{10} f(u) du$$

How do I go about putting the $$e^2$$ in?

Comment: If $u=\ln x$ then you should have $f(5u)$ in your integral, yes?  Or did you mean to write that $u=5\ln x$?

Comment: I mean u=5lnx .

Comment: You're done: the limits are transformed already. The answer is $\frac15 \cdot 25$.

Comment: What about the $$e^2$$ and 1? I'm not sure how I transformed that?

Comment: $x_1=1\rightarrow 5\ln 1=0=u_1$ and $x_2=e^2\rightarrow 5\ln (e^2)=5\cdot 2=10=u_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting $u=\ln(x)$, the limit will now vary from $0$ to $2$.
$$ \int_{1}^{e^2} \frac{f(5 \ln(x))}{x}dx= \int_{0}^{2}f(5u)du$$.
Again if I put $5u=k$,
$$\int_{0}^{2}f(5u)du=\frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{10}{f(k)} dk=25/5=5$$

Comment: Thanks so much. Understood why the bounds changed now

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of both $\ln x$ and $\frac 1x$ indicates that it is indeed a good substitution. And you have done it correctly in your edit. Note that the bounds of definite integration are the lower and upper limits of the values of $x$ throughout which you are performing the summation.

When you perform the substitution you transform the $x$ axis to the $5\ln x$ axis thus your bounds will also change. So, $e^2$ is no longer required. Note that the function is $\frac 15$ of the first integral you wrote with respect to $5\ln x$ just as the first integral was with respect to $x$, so they are in fact the same. So, the answer is:

$$\boxed{\frac 15\int_0^{10} f(u)du = \frac 15\int_0^{10} f(x)dx = \frac 15\cdot 25 = \boxed{5}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help.